# querySelectorAll: manipulating nodes

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation, node-set

As far as I have understood, `querySelector` returns a real changeable element while `querySelectorAll` returns a non-live Static Node Set.

I want to adjust the style of all elements fitting to a specific selector. It works fine for the first element with `querySelector`, but not for all matching elements with `querySelectorAll`. I guess that's because the node set is non-live.

Is there a workaround? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `querySelector` returns a single node. `querySelectorAll` returns a set of nodes (the live-ness means the elements in the set won't be removed if you update them).  You need to set a style on each of the elements matched, probably with a loop -- you can't just set a property once for all of them.

So, you probably need to do something like this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.foo');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.color = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried that but it would not work, so I thought it was due to the nodeset not being live. But actually I just forgot to initialize the iterator (=0)...

Answer (score 5):

this will also work..

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.foo'), function (el) {
    el.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

Comment: Its interesting to me that the above works, but  `document.querySelectorAll('div.foo').forEach(function (e1) ...` doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, which doesn't have forEach.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F

Answer (score 1):

As described in [querySelectorAll: manipulating nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309816/queryselectorall-manipulating-nodes/22480502#22480502) but with a way to make it work, since `forEach` only works on Arrays, not on NodeLists:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.foo')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.color = 'blue';
});
```